# Different proof for; in a convex set $ A,\ \bar { \mathring{ A }} \supset\bar A $?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that   in a convex set  $ A, \mathring { A}  \neq \emptyset \\ \bar { \mathring{ A }} \supset\bar A   $

I have the following proof. Assuming the result that for $x _1 \in \bar A,\ x _2 \in \mathring { A } \ : \lambda x _1 + (1-\lambda )x_2 \in \mathring { A }, \ \lambda \in (0,1) $

Let $x\in \bar A $, and pick $y \in \mathring { A } $, then $ \lambda x + (1-\lambda )y \in \mathring { A }$, for $\lambda \in (0,1) $. Letting $\lambda \to 1^- $gives $x \in \bar { \mathring{ A }}$

Can you prove this differently, especially without the limit operation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you want to include $A^\circ \not= \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes the interior has to be nonempty.

Comment: Stacking one symbol over the other shows why it's sometimes good to use $\operatorname{int}$ and $\operatorname{cl}$ for interior and closure...

Answer (score 0):

Convexity is not needed. You only need $$ \mathring A\subseteq A$$
and 
$$A\subseteq B\implies\overline A\subseteq \overline B $$

Comment: I had the set inclusion the wrong way!